# (Scheme) Take away decimal from a number (i.e 42.0 -> 42)

Tags: vector, scheme, decimal, racket

I have a vector of size 700000 with all zeroes inside of it. I am trying to change the value in an index to 1. I get the index by a calculation. Here's the code:

```
#lang racket

; Make bitvector
(define bitvector (make-vector 700000 0))

; Fill indices
(define fillvector
  (lambda (hashlist dict)
    (cond [(null? hashlist) (cdr dict)]
          [(null? dict) '()]
          [else (vector-set! bitvector ((car hashlist) (car dict)) 1) (fillvector (cdr hashlist) dict)]
    )
))
```

I call `fillvector` like this: `(fillvector hashfl-1 dictionary)`. `dictionary` is a bunch of words:

```
(define dictionary '( (h e l l o)
                      (w a y)
                      (r a i n b o w) ))
```

I get this error after I run that command:

```
vector-set!: contract violation
  expected: exact-nonnegative-integer?
  given: 415458.0
  argument position: 2nd
  other arguments...:
   '#(0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0...
   1
```

I believe the error is because the multiplication method can return a decimal value (though I made sure it would always be .0). Is there anything else I can do? Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The procedure for converting a floating-point ("inexact") number to a non-floating-point ("exact") number is `inexact->exact` (or `exact` in R6RS and R7RS).

```
> (inexact->exact 415458.0)
415458
```